# Combining jQuery with SQL

Tags: jquery, mysql, jquery-plugins

I've made a timepicker, using the pickadate.js add-on for jQuery(http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/time.htm), for appointment uses. The idea is that people could select a time from the input field to make an appointment. To avoid multiples appointments at the same time I'd like to remove options that have already been taken by other users like so:

```
$('.timepicker').pickatime({
disable: [


]})
```

I'd like to have a sql result disabled. The sql query would look something like this:

```
SELECT time FROM Appointments WHERE date='$date'
```

The query would return the times on which appointments have already been made.

So how do I get the query result between the disable brackets, what's the best way?
I've never had to combine jQuery and SQL so I have no clue at all. Tried looking on the internet but couldn't find anything relevant.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This is for the logic layer of the application. Simply use PHP or Python or whatever framework you have to insert the query result between the brackets of the javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, combining JavaScript and SQL is pretty much always a bad idea. (At least for a web page.) Your users should never have direct access to the database. Instead, I personally would do something like this:

- Create a page on your site that accesses the database for the user. This isn't a normal page, but instead outputs JSON, which is widely supported in JavaScript. I would scan the database for all "Events" in a month, and include these in the JSON. See [JSON at MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JSON) for more information, or [this](http://xkcd.com/info.0.json) for an example of output.
- Use [XmlHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or jQuery's own [getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/) to retrieve the event data from the special page.
- Use the data in this JSON object to build your date picker. If you need to refresh the information, you can just have your JavaScript make the request again.

The page between the user and the database is important. One reason is that it hides implementation details from the user. (i.e., your database) You can change the location of your database, or even the type of database, and as long as the interface page is changed to match, the user won't be affected. Another (and more important) reason is that it allows you to do validation of the user's input. It's good rule when developing web applications to assume that *anything from the user cannot be trusted*. If the user had direct access to the database, they could do all sorts of damage.

**tl;dr**

Your database is a server-side tool. JavaScript/jQuery is a client-side tool. Getting data from the DB to the client requires you to build some sort of interface page. (I recommend using JSON to encapsulate this data.)